# Cannot run neo4j on safari, firefox

Tags: macos, neo4j, safari

I have installed neo4j on my mac, but when I try to get connected by typing `localhost:7474` safari says that it can't find the server "localhost". The same problem occurs on Firefox, too. What can I try?

Comment: start the server first, so you can connect to it.

Comment: does your `/etc/hosts` file include `127.0.0.1       localhost`?

Comment: Can you connect directly via loopback address on safari/firefox? `http://127.0.0.1:7474`

Comment: @manonthemat The answer to both questions is "yes".

Comment: Well, that's good. So you have a way of connecting. Now what address do you have set for `org.neo4j.server.webserver.address` in your neo4j-server.properties file (Neo4j 2.x) or if using 3.x, `dbms.connector.http.address` in neo4j.conf?

Comment: @manonthemat I guess I have to check that through the `neo4j.conf` file. Well, I use the 3.04 version  and the the `dbms.connector.http.address` is actually a comment, but its value is set to `0.0.0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I found an answer to the problem (at least in my case). The key is to edit the `/etc/hosts` file and more specifically to comment the line `::1` (by adding the hash symbol at the beginning of the line).

After that, everything seemed to worked fine. This [superuser link](https://superuser.com/questions/30827/safari-is-unable-to-reach-localhost-127-0-0-1) seemed to help a lot.

This [link](http://www.imore.com/how-edit-your-macs-hosts-file-and-why-you-would-want) provides information on how to edit the `hosts` file.

Answer (score 1):

Glad you found your solution, however, a well formatted `/etc/hosts` file on a mac should look closer to this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost                                                                                                                                                        
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost                                                                                                                                                
::1             localhost
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, but it seems there is a problem with `IPV6`, that's why they suggest commenting that specific line. Anyway, if someone can suggest a more elegant solution, I would be glad to follow it.